# Encrypted connection string can not be decrypted

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, rsa, connection-string

I'm about to publish my application, but I want my connection strings to be encrypted.

> aspnet_regiis -pef "sectionName of web.config" "path"

The command above does the job, I publish my application to the server and 
run the following command on the server machine:

> aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "identityOfMyAppPool"

But when I try to browse my application I get the following error:

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Message: Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One instance where this error message is returned is when an RSA key with 2048 bits is used to encrypt the web.config, and an attempt is made to decrypt with a 1024 bit RSA key. Double-check to make sure you have the same key on both machines (all you need is the public portion of the key on the encrypting machine).

By default, the NetFrameworkConfigurationKey is different on each machine (and non-exportable?). To deploy an encrypted web.config from another machine, you need to export the public key from the destination machine and use it to encrypt (or follow all the tutorials and create your own key and put it on both machines...).

Comment: My case is I move the source code, including web.config, from the development server to my development machine. I then try to decrypt in my machine. Fail. I decrypt in the server. OK. Server is 64 bit and my machine is 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

aspnet_regiis -pe "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "identityOfMyAppPool"

instead of

aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "identityOfMyAppPool"

According to aspnet_regiis  /help or aspnet_regiis  /?

-pe

Encrypt the configuration section. Optional arguments:
[-prov provider] Use this provider to encrypt.
[-app virtual-path] Encrypt at this virtual path. Virtual
path must begin with a forward slash. If it is '/', then it
refers to the root of the site. If -app is not specified,
the root web.config will be encrypted.
[-site site-name-or-ID] The site of the virtual path
specified in -app. If not specified, the default web site
will be used.
[-location sub-path] Location sub path.
[-pkm] Encrypt/decrypt the machine.config instead of
web.config.

-pa

Add access for the account to the container. Argu
 [-pku] User container instead of machine containe
 [-csp provider] Csp Provider to use.
 [-full] Add full access (default is Read access).

Comment: But I do the encryption by this command aspnet_regiis -pef "sectionName of web.config" "path". My problem occurs when using the encrypted connection string. The -pa parameter exists in msdn documentation ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx ). Anyway I tried your solution but it did not work.